# Error Msg: replace with Series.rolling(window=5).corr(other=<Series>)

Tags: python, pandas, correlation, rolling-computation

I am trying to find the rolling correlation of 5 periods between columns ['High'] and ['Low'].

I manage to calculate it but there is an error:

> FutureWarning: pd.rolling_corr is deprecated for Series and will be removed in a future version, replace with 
>       Series.rolling(window=5).corr(other=)

Tried replacing it but it doesnt work. Any help?

```
import pandas as pd
df_Gold = pd.read_csv('GoldData.csv')
df_Gold['High_Low'] = pd.rolling_corr(df_Gold['High'],df_Gold['Low'],5)
print(df_Gold.tail())
```

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_corr.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
df['Col1'].rolling(5).corr(df['Col2'])#pandas V 0.20
```

---

***Notice***

```
pd.rolling_corr(df['Col1'],df['Col2'],window=5)#panda V 0.17 (notice pd.rolling_corr is deprecated for Series )
```

Comment: Amazing it works thanks alot!! :)

df_Gold['High_Low'] = df_Gold['High'].rolling(5).corr(df_Gold['Low'])